# IE 11 document mode by default

Tags: internet-explorer-11, ie11-developer-tools

By default IE 11 starts with some wired IE 7 settings (emulation mode) that brakes my JS and everything! 2 hours I try to fix this issues! I can go to developer toolbar F12 and there set the emulator to IE 10 and then it works.

I don't want to go every time in the developer toolbar and set that manually. And on top of that I have to keep the developer toolbar on in order to see the emulator IE 10 working fine!

I'm going nuts with this settings! How can I set IE 11 to start by default in IE 10 or 11 or whatever I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think any of the IE setting lets you configure the default document mode. However, you can achieve this by code in your webpage.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

Putting this line of code in `head` tag of your `HTML` ensures it always uses the latest version of IE.

Or

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=100" />
```

To use a specific version. IE 10, in this case.

Comment: I have my laptop with Win 8.1 and IE 11 and a virtual machine with Win Server 2012 R2 IE 11. The same webpage works in Win 8.1 but it brakes in Win Server ... cannot undertaker it because I don't use the meta tag in any of them. One it works other it brakes!